# Two-way synchronization between View Objects

Tags: oracle-adf

I have two view objects in Oracle ADF.

LineVO represents order lines -- with one line per product.

Products are differentiated by several attributes... say "model" and "color".  So, VO #1 contains a row for each model/color combination.

ModelVO represents a model-level summary of the lines.

Both VOs have a "quantity" field (an Integer).

There is a ViewLink between them and each has a row accessor to the other.

I want to achieve two-way coordination between these two view objects, such that:

- When a user queries data, ModelVO.Quantity equals the sum of LineVO.Quantity, for the associated rows
- When a user updates any LineVO.Quantity, the ModelVO.Quantity is immediately updated to reflect the new total
- When a user updates a ModelVO.Quantity, the quantity is spread among the associated LineVO rows (according to complex business logic which I hope is not relevant here).

I have tried many different ways to do this and cannot get it perfect.

Right now, I am working on variations where ModelVO.Quantity is set to a Groovy expression "LineVO.sum('Quantity')".  Unfortunately, everything I try either has the summing from LineVO->ModelVO working or the spreading from ModelVO->LineVO working, but never both at the same time.

Can someone suggest a way to do this?  I want to do it in the model layer (either a EO or VO or combination).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind..  it turns out to be simple:

`ModelVO.Quantity` must be set to a Groovy "LineVO.sum('Quantity')" and it must have a `recalcExpression` set to a method where I can control things so it only recalculates when I am changing a `LineVO.Quantity` value.

The reason my approach didn't work initially was because, when the user updated a `LineVO.Quantity` value and I wanted to recalculate, I was getting the `ModelVO` row by `lineVORow.getModelVO()`... i.e., via a view accessor.

Apparently, that returns some sort of internal copy of the row and not the actual row.

When I got the parent row via the `applicationModule.getModelVO().getCurrentRow()`, the whole thing works perfectly.

I've posted another question about why accessing the row via the view accessor did not work.  That part is still a mystery to me.